# Apache Xdebug Error After Manually Compiling on Catalina

Tags: macos, xdebug, macos-catalina

I have been struggling to get Xdebug to work with PHP 7.2, and the latest version of Apache on Mac OS Catalina.

A lot of issues due to Apple SIP I assume.  I was finally able to compile it from source via the following step-by-step:
[https://profilingviewer.com/installing-xdebug-on-catalina.html]

Which was a major step forward as nothing else worked to compile or install in.  Now I get the following error in my apache log when starting apache:

```
Failed loading /usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_post_startup_cb
  Referenced from: /usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/php/extensions/xdebug.so
```

Has anyone seen this or has been successful in getting this setup to work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually explains the problem you're having. SImply repeating the tag information does not convey any information. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future user of this site who is scanning a list of search results to find a problem solution. Your current title does not provide that information. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mac Catalina Install Xdebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672354/mac-catalina-install-xdebug)